# Nuxt js application not running on AWS beanstalk - 502 error

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nuxt.js

I have a **Nuxt js** application which needs to be deployed the **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**. I'm using bitbucket internal CI/CD to deploy my application to ELB. The application is successfully deployed as per Bitbucket. But in the AWS Beanstalk console, the health is degraded and hence shows **502 Bad Gateway** error when URL is visited.

I have checked AWS logs, here they are (doesn't show any error):

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/

> stack-web@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
> nuxt start

â„¹ Listening on: http://<IP_ADDRESS>:5100/ // â„¹ --> This is some werid character appearing
```

I have checked my upload `.zip` file it contains `.nuxt` folder and inside that, it has `dist` folder as well. The `dist` folder contains 2 folders `client` and `server`.

Below is my project dir structure. Please help me with this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to mention `process.env.PORT` inside `nuxt.config.js`.

Inside your file under `server` property update the value as:

```
server: {
  port: process.env.PORT || 5100,
  host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
}
```